# shell script to install a package if not alreay installed

Tags: shell, package

I have made a C program, but it depends on the ncurses library. So, when i give my code to anyone else, I have to ask him/her to install ncurses library first then only compile the code using the Makefile i provided.

However, I want to write a shell script which will automatically install `ncurses` if it is NOT already installed. So that I can simply ask my friend to run the script.

This is what i want the script to do ::

```
if(ncurses-dev package not installed)
     sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev
```

I know it is a very basic question, but i dont know how to do it. I tried google search but could not find a simple tutorial which i could understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`For fedora`**

```
if ! rpm -qa | grep -qw $package_name$; then
    yum install $package_name
fi
```

**`For UBUNTU`**

```
#!/bin/sh

for package; do
    dpkg -s "$package" >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
        echo "$package is installed."
    } || {
        sudo apt-get install $package
    }
done
```

This can be used for checking multiple packages as well.

Comment: @sps - are you going to run this script only on UBUNTU or on any linux distribution.

Comment: my c program is for any linux system .... but for now I want to at least get the script working for Debian (ubuntu)... i am writing this reply from my phone ... i will get back to my pc after 2-3 hours, then I can try the script u suggested.. appreciate your help , and already upvoted ur answer , but can't accept it until I test on my pc..

Comment: Yes this works for `ubuntu`. Thanks.. I dont have `red hat` linux to check for `yum` though ...

Comment: For Fedora/RedHat/CentOS/OracleLinux, it is more efficient to query the package name directly instead of `grep`ping for it. `yum list installed package_name` or `rpm -q package_name` will both exit with status `0` when package is installed or non-zero if package is missing.

Comment: what about macOS?

Answer (score 0):

To automatically install without user interaction on Debian(In your case Ubuntu), you could use the --force-yes --yes switches in your command line args list. Like so:

sudo apt-get --force-yes --yes install package